# How to read HTML file all DOM element label value using C#?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

I want read a html file all DOM element label and change that label value to another language and store that file to another location.

Comment: And do you have a question ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A tool commonly recommended retrieving the DOM this is the [Html Agility Pack](http://html-agility-pack.net/). It will take malformed HTML and massage it into XHTML and then a traversable DOM.

There are some examples and the API documentation here:

http://html-agility-pack.net/api

Some useful links:

- [How to use HTML Agility pack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/846994/how-to-use-html-agility-pack)
- [Parsing HTML Documents with the Html Agility Pack](https://web.archive.org/web/20211020001935/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/011211-1.aspx)
- [Crawling a web sites with HtmlAgilityPack](http://www.beletsky.net/2010/09/crawling-web-sites-with-htmlagilitypack.html)
- [Getting Started With HTML Agility Pack](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/9b86d4/getting-started-with-html-agility-pack/)